# Modelling Optional relationships from a set

Tags: graph, neo4j

So my graph has green nodes which are related to blue nodes as requirements. The idea is that the user has set of blue nodes which should match the requirments of a green node in order to be compatible with the green node.

[image]

But the problem comes when requirments are specified as combinations. eg To be compatible for green node 1 you need to have blue nodes A, E and any 2 blue nodes from the set (BCD).

My question is; is this a reasonable way to modeling this, given the kind of query specified? I've also been thinking to add for instance, a yellow combo node which then connects to these combinational blue nodes and have 'any 2' as a property. Would that be easier to write queries for? ie Give me all green nodes which are compatible with the user given their blue nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think having `Combo` nodes is the right way to go.

A `Combo` node can have a `minCount` property that specifies the minimum count, which could be any positive number. Also, this approach would allow a green node to have multiple `Combo` nodes with the same `minCount` (but pointing to different blue nodes) -- something that would not be possible with your current data model.